# codeigniter cannot echo site_url in separate js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, url

I have a code to insert a data from my database. I use ajax and i separate it with js file. When i separate a js file for my ajax. I cannot echo the `echo site_url()` from it. I already autoload the url helper. When i tried to put in below in my view, i can echo my site_url.

Here is my separate js code:

```
function create_clinic() {
  alert("<?php echo site_url(clinic)?>");
    $('#btnCreateClinic').text('Saving...');
    $('#btnCreateClinic').attr('disabled',true);


    $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo site_url('clinic_admin/create_clinic')?>",
          type: "POST",
          data: $('#frm_create_clinic').serialize(),
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data)
          {
          if(data.status) {
            alert('Added Sucessfuly');
          }
          else
          {
              for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
              {
                  $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); 
                  $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
              }
          }
          $('#btnCreateClinic').text('Save'); //change button text
          $('#btnCreateClinic').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable 


          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
              alert('Error adding data' + jqXHR+ textStatus +errorThrown);
              $('#btnCreateClinic').text('Save'); 
              $('#btnCreateClinic').attr('disabled',false); 

          }
      }); 
}
```

and i got error in console with this:
403 (Forbidden) - A forbidden Access.

here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /clinic/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @abdulla Nilam thank you for you comment sir, i named it with customjs.js   and include it in footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `.htaccess` like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

And in the code

```
url : "<?php echo base_url();?>clinic_admin/create_clinic", # with htaccess
```

or

```
url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/clinic_admin/create_clinic", # withour  htaccess
```

---

> > **before that check `create_clinic()` js function is working/reaching.**

Comment: /clinic/<?php%20echo%20site_url(%27clinic_admin/create_clinic%27)?> Here is the output sir

Comment: where is this Js function added ??

Comment: i can access my controller when i type the url sir. my problem is , i cannot echo the base_url sir.. how can i do it? i separate my js file at footer

Comment: no then you cant. base URL only works with `.php` extension

Comment: go to your config/config.php and set base URL

Comment: its already good sir, but still i cannot alert the site_url in my separated js file. when i alert it below in my view it gives me output of this http://[::1]/clinic, but when i go to my separate js file it gives me the output of <?php echo site_url()?> , instead of http://[::1]/clinic

Comment: go to `application/config/config.php` and set ur base URL. its empty. thts y u get output like `http://[::1]/`. Ex: `http://localhost/stackoverflow`

Comment: @JcJohn its ok. happy to help :)